# How to log two messages in one line

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I would like NLog to create just one line in the log file for the following code:

```
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
log.Trace("Operation starting.")
StartOperation();
log.Trace("Finished. Elapsed time = {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Currently it results in two log lines.
With Console.Write I can achieve desired result by writing:

```
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Console.Write("Operation starting.")
StartOperation();
Console.WriteLine("Finished. Elapsed time = {0} ms",stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

But any call to NLog logger writes every new entry in a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. A logger has one task: To report what happens at a single given time. The start of an operation happens at time x, while it finishes at time x + 10 seconds. Furthermore, between those two times, a lot of other stuff can happen. The operation itself could log much more information. Other tasks can log information. Should all these lines be concatenated?

If you want to concat those two lines, concat them yourself:

```
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
string log = "Operation starting. ";
StartOperation();
log.Trace(log + "Operation starting. Finished. Elapsed time = {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

which is the same as:

```
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
StartOperation();
log.Trace("Operation starting. Operation starting. Finished. Elapsed time = {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Which immediately shows how "weird" this is...

Comment: I wanted use logging to show progress in the console window. You are right, such log looks weird in a file.

Comment: Showing progress and logging are two different concepts. You should program them seperately.